# What is External Content Table? What is the advantages over normal virtual tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

What are external content tables and how can they be used instead of fts3 virtual tables for Full Text Search? Is it worth to use fts4 instead of fts3?

Comment: What specific part of [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#*fts4content) do you not understand?

Comment: I am not understanding how external content table avoid duplicate copies of data

Comment: See [shadow tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#*shadowtab).

Comment: So it does copy the data for specified columns? But the documentation says that external content table can access the columns that it does not have. but I cannot figure out how to use it?

Comment: There are examples.

Comment: Wait just read the example. it says that it takes data from the content table when requested. So it does not copy the data. Am I correct?